# My pipeline not imputing values correctly?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm new to python and have been learning about pipelines from datacamp. I have been experimenting with some fifa data that has missing NaN values. I have tried to create a pipeline with the steps of imputing any missing data (replacing it with the mean) and then creating a logistic regression. I don't seem to get any errors in the output. However, when I print things such as print(x_train) and print(y_pred) the output still returns NaN values. Would that indicate that my Pipeline is not working and that the data was not correctly imputed as surely I should be seeing the mean values rather than NaN. Would appreciate if someone could answer the question in layman's terms as I am new to the topic.

```
fif_data=pd.read_csv("fifa_draft_1.csv")

df_Foot_Dummy=pd.get_dummies(fif_data, drop_first=True) 


imp=SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy="mean")

logreg=LogisticRegression()


x=df_Foot_Dummy["passing"].values.reshape(-1,1)
y=df_Foot_Dummy["preferred_foot_Right"]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state=42)

steps=[("imputation", imp),("logistic_regression",logreg)]
pipe=Pipeline(steps)
pipe.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred=pipe.predict(x_test)
print(x_train)
print(y_pred)
```

Comment: Hi, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples and update your code so we all can run the same thing. For instance you can replace the first line so we all have a sample of data into `fif_data`

Comment: Please print the shapes of x, x_train, x_test, y, y_train and y_test

Answer (score 1):

Pipelines do not change data in-place; at each step, the data is modified and passed along, but the intermediate results are not saved (with a partial exception when the `cache` parameter is set).

That the logistic regression doesn't complain indicates that the imputation has in fact happened.

`y_pred` shouldn't have any missing values; if that's the case, please let us know and provide an example dataset.